# MySQL Connector not working | Django 1.10 | Windows | Python 3.5

Tags: python, mysql, django

For many months now I've been wanting to use MySQL and all of it's awesomeness for my django python website but keep running in to the same error. I've installed and reinstalled the official Oracle MySQL connector (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html) and various packages like MySQLClient from the fork (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) which gives me a error.

> Wheel not supported

When I utilize the back-end code specified on the docs page for the MySQL connector I get the same error in the server window.

> ImportError: No module named 'mysql'

In my `settings.py`, this is the line where it errors out, attempting to import

```
imort os
import mysql.connector #this is where it errors out
```

Pages I've looked at:
 - stackoverflow.com/questions/37848035/mysql-connector-python-as-django-engine
 - stackoverflow.com/questions/26573984/django-how-to-install-mysql-connector-python-with-pip3
 - docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/
and many more. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem was that I was trying to install unnecessary connectors.In my case mysql-connector worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing "mysql-connector", with the dash "-"? I think it is still imported by "import mysql.connector", but installs differently.
This is the thing that seems to work for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

when using Oracle connector, your configuration should contain this :

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

But why do you want to use it? I would recommend the common `mysqlclient` instead of the Oracle connector.

```
$ pip install mysqlclient    # python 2 and 3
```

Comment: I've tried installing the `mysqlclient` package and get and error (both with easy_install and pip) "could not include file 'my_config.h': No file or directory exists...exited with status 2", and I've tried using the `.django` in the engine item, it still makes no difference since I can't even import it.